# Change URL in Web Address in Browser, but Don't Go There

Tags: javascript, location-href

I know that the following JavaScript code instructs the browser to insert the specified URL string into the address bar AND go there:

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.john-doe.com/';
```

However, what I want to do is to only change the URL that appears in the address bar, but don't actually go to that URL.

How can I do this?

Comment: `document.location.href` is a javascript function that will redirect the user, why you used this function if you don't want to redirect them?

Comment: You really can't do what you want to do. Why would you even consider doing this? It sounds fishy to me....

Answer (score 2):

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'hi', '/hi')
```

More at [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Edit: This can only change the path, not the domain or protocol.

Comment: Worth mentioning that ["The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)

Comment: Yes. The example of the question seems to refer to a whole new domain.

Comment: Here is a more clear description of what I want to do:

1. User is currently at http://splash.john-doe.com
2. Use JavaScript to change http://splash.john-doe.com to http://www.john-doe.com but don't actually go to http://www.john-doe.com.

Comment: @JoelMeine The origin can't be changed.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to change the browser URL via code without going to it. For security reasons I suppose.

Comment: Think about a malicious web site that change is address to your mail site and say: "Welcome back, I need your password".

Comment: Incorrect. `history.pushState` does exactly this.

Comment: There is a big limit, in history.pushState the new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL

Comment: True, but that's far from not being possible at all.